# SSIS reading csv produced by My Sql, code page conflict

Tags: ssis

I've got a 3rd party file coming in - utf-8 encoded, 56 columns, csv export from MySql.  My intent is to load it into a Sql Server 2019 instance - a table layout I do not have control over.

Sql Server Import Wizard will automatically do the code page conversions to latin 1 (and a couple string-to-int conversions) but it will not handle the MySql "\N" for null conventions, so I thought I'd try my hand at SSIS to see if I could get the data cleaned up on ingestion.

I got a number of components set up to do various filtering and transforming (like the "\N" stuff) and that was all working fine.  Then I tried to *save* the data using an OLE DB destination, and the wheels kinda fall off the cart.

SSIS appears to drop all of the automatic conversions Import Wizard would do and force you to make the conversions explicit.

I add a Data Transformation Component into the flow and edit all 56 columns to be explicit about the various conversions - only it lets me edit the "Copy of" output column code pages *it will not save them*.  Either in the Editor or the Advanced Editor.

I saw another article here saying "Use the Derived Column Transformation" but that seems to be on a column-by-column basis (so I'd have to add 56 of them).

It seems kinda crazy that SSIS is such a major step backwards in this regard from Import Wizard, bcp, or BULK INSERT.

Is there a way to get it to work through the code page switch in SSIS using SSIS components?  All the components I've seen recommended don't seem to be working and all of the other articles say "make another table using different code pages or NVARCHAR and then copy one table to the other" which kinda defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took synthesizing a number of different posts on tangentially related issues, but I think I've finally gotten SSIS to do a lot of what Import Wizard and BULK INSERT gave for free.

It seems that to read a utf-8 csv file in with SSIS and to process it all the way through to a table that's in 1252 and not using NVARCHAR involves the following:

1. Create a Flat File Source component and set the incoming encoding to 65001 (utf-8).  In the Advanced editor, convert all string columns from DT_STR/65001 to DT_WSTR (essentially NVARCHAR).  It's easier to work with those outputs the rest of the way through your workflow, and (most importantly) a Data Conversion transform component won't let you convert from 65001 to any other code page.  But it *will* let you convert from DT_WSTR to DT_STR in a different code page.

1a) SSIS is pretty annoying about putting a default 50 length on everything by default.  And not carrying through any lengths as defaults from one component/transform to the next.  So you have to go through and set the appropriate lengths on all the "Column 0" input columns from the Flat File Source *and* all the WSTR transforms you create in that component.

1b) If your input file contains, as mine apparently does, invalid utf-8 encoding now and then, choose "RD_RedirectRow" as the Truncation error handling for every column.  Then add a Flat File Destination to your workflow, and attach the red line coming out of your Flat File Source to it.  That's if you want to see what row was bad.  You can just choose "RD_IgnoreError" if you don't care about bad input.  But leaving the default means your whole package will blow up if it hits any bad data

2. Create a Script transform component, and in that script you can check each column for the MySql "\N" and change it to null.
3. Create a Data Conversion transformation component and add it to your workflow.  Because of the DT_WSTR in step 1, you can now change that output back to a DT_STR in a different code page here.  If you don't change to DT_WSTR from the get-go, the Data Conversion component will not work changing the code page at this step.  99% of the data I'm getting in just has latinate characters, utf-8 encoded (the accents).  There are a smattering of kanji characters in a small subset of data, so to reproduce what Import Wizard does for you, you must change the Truncation error handling on every column here that might be impacted to RD_IgnoreError.  Unlike some documentation I read, RD_IgnoreError does not put null in the column; it puts the text with the non-mapping characters replaced with "?" like we're all used to.
4. Add your OLE DB destination component and map all of the output columns from step 3 to the columns of your database.

So, a lot of work to get back to Import Wizard started and to start getting the extra things SSIS can do for you.  And SSIS can be kind of annoying about snapping column widths back to the default 50 when you change something.  If you've got a lot of columns this can get pretty tedious.